# ios voice recording during the ringing session

Tags: ios, multitasking, audio-recording

Any Idea if and how to achieve the following requirement:

per incoming call,  in all scenarios (call accept/ reject / hanging etc) - I would like to open the mic and record  to a file during the ringing session (up to 30 sec).

in case of call accept - application must not record the call in case.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not possible to do this, iOS takes away the audio session from you as soon as the phone is ringing and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: so continuos recording that cover voice calls as well can not be done. ps

Comment: Right. It would be a huge security/privacy problem if it was possible. Or would you trust a phone where normal apps could easily record your phone calls and possible send them to someone else ? :-)